# SQL Oracle Find Max of count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table called item:

```
| PERSON_id        | ITEM_id        |
|------------------|----------------|
|------CP2---------|-----A03--------|
|------CP2---------|-----A02--------|
|------HB3---------|-----A02--------|
|------BW4---------|-----A01--------|
```

I need an SQL statement that would output the person with the most Items. Not really sure where to start either.

Comment: Sorry meant *need*

Comment: Hint:  start with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What happens if more than one person have an equal number of items and all are the maximum? Do you want all of them returned? or only one? (if one,  why "that one"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to use inner query for this purpose. the inner query is going to include group by and order by statement. and outer query will select the first statement which has the most items.

```
SELECT * FROM 
( 
  SELECT PERSON_ID, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1 
  GROUP BY PERSON_ID
  ORDER BY 2 DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

here is the fiddler link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c4228/5

Comment: Cheers, that helped alot:))

Answer (score 0):

Locating the maximum of an aggregated column requires more than a single calculation, so here you can use a "common table expression" (cte) to hold the result and then re-use that result in a where clause:

```
with cte as (
    select
          person_id
        , count(item_id) count_items
    from mytable
    group by
         person_id
    )
select
*
from cte
where count_items = (select max(count_items) from cte)
```

Note, if more than one person shares the same maximum count; more than one row will be returned bu this query.